# Develop native app (c++) for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, native

I would like to know that:

1. is there any tool to jailbreak / unlock WP7 ?
2. Is it possible to develop native app use C++ for W)7 after we unlock/jail broken to take root privilege ? Which tools should I use?

Answer (score 1):

There are such tools yes, but no. You cannot not build native C++ application on the Windows Phone 7 Series.

Comment: As far as I known, once a phone is unlocked, we can take root privilege. So, is it possible to upload an app to it like we can do with iPhone ?

Comment: There was something of an hack around for a while but it was all about installing unsigned application (by passing the Marketplace). However, there are no public APIs on the phone that you can use for native development. Even if you managed to access the hardware what then? There's also the possibility that Microsoft will patch any vulnerability that you're currently exploiting to do something like this which frankly shouldn't be done.